# Now that I've converted my primary keys to GUIDs, how do I fix the performance?

Tags: primary-key, guid, auto-increment, toplink

I'm using TopLink as my ORM and MySQL as the DB.

I traded my auto-increment primary keys for GUIDs for one of my tables (alright, not quite: I'm actually using a random 64 bit integer, but that's good enough for my needs).

Anyway, now queries, which don't even use the key, are taking much longer.

What can I do?

Comment: You changed your guaranteed to be unique auto-incremented primary key to a 64-bit random value that will produce duplicates? Why?

Comment: well... to take advantage of the benefits that GUIDs offer.  and in my case, if a duplicate occurs, the application will just try again.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/

Answer (score 1):

If your table is indexed by the fields your are querying by. content of the key shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact. They maybe something else there .

Comment: i have a field that represents the creationDate.  how can i force my table to be index accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the key column really is the PRIMARY KEY and thus the clustered (physical) index.

Make sure you have indexes that hit your common queries.

---

*Random* integer? You realize there's a chance of hitting the same pri key?

Comment: Lets hope that he doesn't have a bad PRNG and accidentally get the same seed, so he has to test all keys over and over...

Comment: primary key is clustered only if he's using innodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using innodb tables in MySQL [all rows are referred to by primary key](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/) so if you're using a secondary key performance will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

> i have a field that represents the creationDate. how can i force my table to be index accordingly?

```
create index Table_creationDate on Table(creationDate);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "force my table to index"? That's not a database concept I'm familiar with.

Comment: i guess i just meant create an index
what Frank Krueger answered was helpful